# Is there a random function in python that accepts variables?

Tags: python, random

I'm attempting to create a simple dice roller, and I want it to create a random number between 1 and the number of sides the dice has. However, `randint` will not accept a variable. Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do?

code below:

```
import random
a=0
final=0
working=0

sides = input("How many dice do you want to roll?")

while a<=sides:
    a=a+1
    working=random.randint(1, 4)
    final=final+working

print "Your total is:", final
```

Comment: I've cleaned up code to remove irrelevant bits

Comment: What does "will not accept a variable" mean?  That's not sensible.  please provide the actual error message you're actually getting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If looks like you're confused about the number of dice and the number of sides

I've changed the code to use `raw_input()`.  `input()`is not recommended because Python
literally evaluates the user input which could be malicious python code

```
import random
a=0
final=0
working=0

rolls = int(raw_input("How many dice do you want to roll? "))
sides = int(raw_input("How many sides? "))

while a<rolls:
    a=a+1
    working=random.randint(1, sides)
    final=final+working

print "Your total is:", final
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to pass sides to `randint`, for example like this:

```
working = random.randint(1, int(sides))
```

also, it's not the best practice to use `input` in python-2.x. please, use `raw_input` instead, you'll need to convert to number yourself, but it's safer.

Answer (score 1):

Try randrange(1, 5)

[Generating random numbers in Python](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/how-do-i-generate-random-numbers-in-python.htm)

Answer (score 1):

random.randint accepts a variable as either of its two parameters.  I'm not sure exactly what your issue is.

This works for me:

```
import random

# generate number between 1 and 6
sides = 6
print random.randint(1, sides)
```